# Collapsible bootstrap, show first element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I want to show the first element of this collapsible accordion. I did some research in internet but in vain

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne" >
        Aller au dossier personnel d'un agent
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <form action="goToAgent.do" method="post">
          <p align="center">
            <input type="hidden" value="identite" name="retour">
            <label for="nomPrenom" >
              Entrer le nom complet de l'agent:
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="nomPrenom" class="typeahead" /> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="appliquer" class="btn btn-info" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
        Ajout d'un nouveau fonctionnaire
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <!-- lorem -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you've got all the HTML you need for the accordion to work unless you haven't pasted it all above.

The Bootstrap docs first example has the first element set to be open:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse (These docs are for v2.3.2, which is no longer officially supported.)

I think it's the class "in" that sets it to be open initially.

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
Collapsible Group Item #1
</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
<div class="accordion-inner">
Anim pariatur cliche...
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-group">
<div class="accordion-heading">
<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
Collapsible Group Item #2
</a>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
Anim pariatur cliche...
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

Update for v4 :

The class `.show` can be used on the `.collapse` element to open it.

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-parent">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne"></a> 
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion-parent"></div>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo"></a> 
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-parent"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the same example working with v4 : [Demo v4 (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/yYuRz/139/)

---

Bootstrap v2

If you add the `.in` class to the `.collapse`, it stays open :

```html
<div class="accordion-group">  
  <div class="accordion-heading">  
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">  
     Ajout d'un nouveau fonctionnaire
    </a>  
  </div>  
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse in"> 
    <div class="accordion-inner">
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/yYuRz/)

---

Here is the demo with a simplified markup : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/yYuRz/2/

You do need to remove the `style="height: 0px;"` from the `.collapse` element if you want it to be displayed.

Comment: Since the newest version of bootstrap, "in" has been replaced by "show". You would have the division have the following class: "collapse show". Reference:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Answer (score 7):

You also can trigger a clic on the first collapse element

```
$("#accordion a:first").trigger("click");
```